# Can I reuse a faucet with new vanity cabinet and counter?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I have a Delta Faucet. We are thinking of installing a totally new vanity, bathroom cabinet and counter. Is there an issue reinstalling the same faucet, installation or maintenance wise? Just curious, wanted to save $80, and bought [this faucet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Delta-Windemere-4-in-Centerset-2-Handle-Bathroom-Faucet-with-Metal-Drain-Assembly-in-Chrome-B2596LF/202813493) last year actually.

[image]

Comment: Just take it apart like you are planning to re-use it, not like you are going to chunk it into a dumpster...

Comment: A one year old faucet with a lifetime warranty ... glad you got the answer you wanted!

Comment: Do note that if the new counter top comes with mounting holes for a faucet, you'll need a faucet that matches that hole spacing. That may or may not be your existing faucet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

No, there is no big issue.

Just make sure you drill the required holes at the correct spacing and check the fixings work with the thickness of the top.

Did something similar for my son, but needed to dismantle the faucet. Works fine now.

Comment: I think you mean, "Yes", etc etc.     :)

Comment: @jay613 "is there an issue…" etc